# Animation, remove blink when a view.visibility(gone) and another view take the space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm dealing with animations, and I'm new with it. I've got this structure in XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Something"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%"/>
```

And my MainActivity looks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
boolean animationOnOff;
LinearLayout ll;
Animation animScroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
    animalNames.add("Horse");
    ....

    animationOnOff = true;
    ll = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    animScroll = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.total_gasto_hide);
    animScroll.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ll.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if(dy > 0) {
                if(animationOnOff) {
                    ll.startAnimation(animScroll);
                    animationOnOff = false;
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

This code should take the `linearLayout1` up and disapear after 300ms with a `visibility(view.GONE)`, so far so good. The problem is that the recyclerview is not getting stick with this animation, and when the `linearLayout1` is gone the recycler instantly get the position of the view gone (Doing some kind of blink effect). Gif below:

[image: Gif]

So my question is, how can I do it to eliminate this blink effect and achieve a smooth interpolation effect when the `linearLayout1` is gone?

Comment: I would suggest you use **CollapsingToolbarLayout** instead of adding hide and gone thing as it works well with recycler view

Answer (score 2):

Android can handle the animation for you by default. Just add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your parent `LinearLayout` and the visibility will be animated.

Comment: If I add this line, the recycler still wait for the linearLayout1 to be hidden to animate. And I want it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use **CoordinatorLayout** with **CollapsingToolbarLayout** and change the **app:layout_scrollFlags** as per your needs

> This will help you to remove the boiler part code which you have added
>   in your Activity

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/cl_newdashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="2dp">

            <!--Toolbar here if you don't want to collapse it-->

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <!--COLLAPSING UI to be added here-->

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_prescriptions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <!--REST OF THE VIEW-->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The UI part which will land inside the **CollapsingToolbarLayout** will hide when the **RecyclerView** is scrolled,

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, because this LinearLayout I have it's below the toolbar, and I can't change the position. For example if I have a TabLayout I want this LinearLayout below the tabs, and when scroll the recycler hide only the LinearLayout.

Comment: You don't need to change much, if you don't want your toolbar to hide put it above the collapsing layout and for the part which you need to hide you can put it inside the collapsingToolbar and whenever the view is scrolled like the LinerLayout/anything put it inside the Collapsing.

Comment: I don't understand you yet. I'm changing my first Linear for a Constraint, then I add the CollapsingToolbarLayout, and inside of it, I put my LineasLayout. Outside the CollapsingToolbarLayout my recycler. But it is doing nothing now. I need some java code or something like that? What I'm doing wrong?